# Using a program(.exe), inside a program, but passing command line arguments on linux C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exec, coredump

I've been trying to call a program inside another c++ program using the command "execvp()" from the <unistd.h> library but it gets core dump, and i dont know what i am doing wrong;

below its the code i use to call the program i want to use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *argument_list[]={argv[1],argv[2],NULL};   
    
    char *filename = "./bin/program.exe";

    execvp(filename, argument_list);

return 0;
}
```

below this, its the code of the program i want to call

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a  = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << a+b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile the the first code, i get a "main.exe" binary, then i type  "main.exe 5 6" to sum both integers, and i get the "core dump" error.
Curious thing is, if i run gdb on it, i get the sum i want

the first command line, its running directly the "child" program, showing that it works. The second command line, its using the "main" program that calls the child one

[image]

(Obviously, this programs aren't the ones i need to apply this, they're just for illustration of the problem, they're really big codes, and it wouldn't be helpful to post them here);

How can i fix this?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation of the functions your calling. In `execvp`, "The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program. **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed**. The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer."

Comment: @Whoz all those requirements seem to be met in the OP's code, unless i am missing something

Comment: Aside: in both of the programs you should check `argc` so that the program arguments accessed are valid, and output an alternative message if not. That at least will guard against fumbling for a solution.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `char *argument_list[]={argv[1],argv[2],NULL}; ` is *not* putting the program name in the first argument. The first argument in the array is traditionally the same as the first argument to `execvp`. That array should be three-args-wide; not two, not including the terminating NULL.

Comment: Note that the coonvention could be very well ignored here, but the second program adheres to it and starts reading from second element, not first one. `argv[2]` is `NULL` in the `program.exe`.

Comment: The convention on Linux is that executables shouldn't have any extension.

Answer (score 0):

So, it works if i set the first argument as the filename, as said by @WhozCraig, so now it works, and looks like this:
#include 
#include <unistd.h>

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    char *argument_list[]={"program.exe",argv[1],argv[2],NULL};
    
    
    char *filename = "./bin/program.exe";

    execvp(filename, argument_list);
return 0;
}
```

However, i get this warning:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZaXX.png)
How can i get around it? Is there a problem leaving it like this?